# Android setRecyclerListener cannot resolve method

Tags: android, listview

I am using `StickyListHeadersListView` library which is found [here](https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyListHeaders)
Like in general `ListView` we could set `listView.setRecyclerListener(new AbsListView.RecyclerListener())`

but 
in `StickyListHeaders` i cannot set `setRecyclerListener`. any suggestion in which way i can use the method `setRecyclerListener` in case of implementing `StickyListHeadersListView`

Answer (score 0):

It's because StickyListHeadersListView extends FrameLayout, not AbsListView.
See https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyListHeaders/blob/master/library/src/se/emilsjolander/stickylistheaders/StickyListHeadersListView.java#L38